# running two code-blocking python scripts at once

Tags: python

i have two pieces of code, one a server and one a discord.py bot
i want them to run seperately and i tried two things in order to achieve this and they both didn't work

first, i tried running the two scripts in batch like this:

```
py main.py
py server.py
```

then i tried using multiprocessing:

```
import multiprocessing
import os

def func1():
  os.system("py main.py")

def func2():
  os.system("py server.py")

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func1)
p1.start()
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func2)
p2.start()
```

but this still didn't work. only the first script ran instead of both, which was what i was looking for
can someone help me?

Comment: `py main.py & && py server.py &` ?

Comment: What os are you running under?   Win, Mac, or Linux?  Also, you could probably try your second one with simple threading instead of multiprocessing, as it calls out to the os, though I haven't tried that myself. Also: Did you try swapping call order?

Comment: i am using windows but i need a solution which will work on linux too as i will be deploying my app to a linux server

Comment: i also just tried swapping the order but it just means the server runs first. like i said, they are code blocking

Comment: The most clean way to achieve this would probably to have a library-like interface to `main.py` and `server.py`, so that you could import them and start them with multi-threading. Keep in mind that if you want to have cross-compatibility, you should avoid at all cost `os.system` calls, because they will (most likely) never work the same way on two different architectures. If you don't like this, the other cleanest solution would be to write a shell script for each supported platform. Doing what you want in bash is very easy.

Comment: i tried 
`import main
import server` with threading only main.py runs